# How to get the current id section in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

When I click in a register of a list, in the url appears something like this:

http://myInstance:8069/web?&debug=#id=9&view_type=form&model=ext.test&action=544

I need to capture the 9 (the value of id) in python in order to pass it as a default value of other field.

I don't know how to capture this value.

I want something similar like this:

```
@api.model
def default_get(self, vals):
    result = super(my_relation, self).default_get(vals)

    result['my_id'] = HERE_GOES_THE_VALUE_OF_THE_ID

    return result
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I realized that the "current id section" is the "active_id" variable. 
However, if I try to access to this variable inside the python code, the value is 'None'.

To solve this problem, I have sent the variable via 'context'. In the xml file:

```
<field name="my_field_name" context="{'my_id': active_id}"/>
```

Then, in the python file, I can access to the context doing this:

```
result['my_id'] = self._context['my_id']
```